# Singapore PR status and re-entry permit

Tags: resident-permit, singapore, cpf

I am a Singapore PR since 2013.

Before that, I was studying in Singapore (2005-2011, BEng/MEng). I started working as an engineer in 2011. I left Singapore in 2015 and my re-entry permit will be expiring in March 2018. Since I don't have a job in Singapore my chances of renewing the re-entry permit are extremely low, perhaps nil.

Is there is a chance I can get the permit renewed if I Volunteer to contribute to the CPF? If so, what are my chances?

If my re-entry permit renewal gets rejected, is it mandatory to renounce my PR?

Can I not renounce my PR, and in a few years' time can I come to Singapore, find a new job, and start working? Should I first get an EP pass and go through the process from beginning or I simply apply for a new re-entry permit?

Comment: Considering the lack of transparency in the new PR system in Singapore, I think the only people who have the answer would be ICA. Have you tried contacting them?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is a chance I can get the permit renewed if I Volunteer to contribute to the CPF? If so, what are my chances?

I don't think volunteering to contribute to CPF when not working is even possible; this is intended mostly for self-employed people.

> If my re-entry permit renewal gets rejected, is it mandatory to renounce my PR?

No.  Your REP lets you *re-enter* Singapore as PR if you leave, but as long as you stay in Singapore, your PR remains valid.

> Can I not renounce my PR, and in a few years' time can I come to Singapore, find a new job, and start working? Should I first get an EP pass and go through the process from beginning or I simply apply for a new re-entry permit?

You don't need to actively renounce a PR, it will simply expire if you leave Singapore without renewing your REP.  (You will, however, need to formally renounce if you want your CPF money back.)  Once your PR is gone, it's gone and it's back to square one.

All that said, in my limited experience (N=2), if you want to renew your REP but don't fulfill all the conditions, you will likely be granted a *one-year* renewal instead of the usual 5.  So I would advise you to return to Singapore, apply while present in Singapore -- you have nothing to lose, right? -- and if you get it, do your hardest to have a job in Singapore in time for the next renewal.